# Haagerup norm on C${}^*$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, tensor-products, tensors, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $E$ and $F$ be C${}^*$-algebras. Let $\|\cdot \|_h $ denote the Haagerup norm defined on the algebraic tensor product $E \odot F$.

> Is the completion of $E \odot F$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_h$ a C${}^*$-algebra?

Comment: Are you talking about tensor products? Why not use $\otimes$?

Comment: I am denoting the algebraic tensor product by $\odot$.

Comment: Can you define the Haagerup norm?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Hi}{\mathcal{H}} \newcommand{\Li}{\mathcal{L}}$

Call $E \otimes_h F$ the completion of $E \odot F$ under $\| \cdot \|_h$. The answer is that $E \otimes_h F$ is usually not a C${}^*$-algebra.

In general, $E \otimes_h F$ is not even an operator algebra. In fact, David Blecher proved on his Ph.D disertation the following result

> **Theorem 1.** $E \otimes_h F$ is an operator algebra if and only if $E$
> or $F$ is finite dimensional.

The best general result we can get is:

> **Theorem 2.** $E \otimes_h F$ is a Banach algebra that is isometrically isomorphic to a subalgebra of $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H}))$ for some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

**Edit:** Here's more detail on how to prove theorem 2. $E \otimes_h F$ is seen as a Banach algebra by extending the usual multiplication
$$
(a \otimes b)(c \otimes d)=(ac)\otimes (db)
$$
from $E \odot F$ to all of $E \otimes_h F$.

Let $(\varphi_E, \Hi_E)$ and $(\varphi_F, \Hi_F)$ the universal representations for the C${}^*$-algebras $E$ and $F$ respectively. Define $\varphi: E \odot F \to \Li(\Li(\Hi_E \oplus \Hi_F))$ on elementary tensors by
$$
\varphi(a \otimes b)(T):= (\varphi_E(a) \oplus 0)T(0 \oplus \varphi_F(b))
$$
for any $T \in \Li(\Hi_E \oplus \Hi_F)$. One can check that this extends to $ E \otimes_h F$ and gives an isometric algebra homomorphism from $E \otimes_h F$ to $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H}_E \oplus \Hi_F))$.

Comment: In the last paragraph it's Banach algebra or Banach space?

Comment: It’s a Banach algebra. And by operator algebra I understand a Banach algebra that can be faithfully represented on a Hilbert space. I can add more detail about how to prove the general result I mention if you think  it’d be helpful.

Comment: Is it done by applying Ruan's theorem?Pls provide details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, I just edited and added some more detail.

Comment: In this are you assuming E and F are finite dimensional?

Comment: No, what I gave is a sketch of the proof of what I just labeled as theorem 2. I don’t remember exactly how the proof of theorem 1 goes, it relies on some characterization of operator algebras. You might want to take a look at David P Blecher’s Phd dissertation for more details on that. That’s were I learned about the Haagerup tensor product.

Comment: In Thm. 1 $ E \otimes_{h} F$ is not even a Banach algebra. But in Thm. 2 it is. I am not understanding this.

Comment: No, in theorem 1 the claim is that it’s not an **operator algebra**. There are Banach algebras that are not operator algebras.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.